# unordered_map from own type by overloading operator() fails

Tags: c++

What's wrong with the `operator()` inside `Entity` (hasher) ?

Copy-pasting it to a separate `struct` works :

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

struct Entity {
  
  string name;
  
  size_t operator()(const Entity& k) const noexcept 
  { return std::hash<string>{}(k.name); }
  
  bool operator== (const Entity& e) const noexcept 
  { return e.name == name; }

};

struct KeyHasher {
  size_t operator()(const Entity& k) const noexcept
  { return std::hash<string>{}(k.name); }
};

int main(){
 // unordered_map<const Entity, bitset<24>, KeyHasher> m1; // OK
 unordered_map<const Entity, bitset<24>> m2; // unordered_map() ill-formed ?
  return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:25:43: error: use of deleted function 'std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map() 
[with _Key = const Entity; _Tp = std::bitset<24>; _Hash = std::hash<const Entity>; _Pred = std::equal_to<const Entity>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Entity, std::bitset<24> > >]'
   25 |   unordered_map<const Entity, bitset<24>> m2;
      |                                           ^~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-cxx-modules-trunk-20220427/include/c++/11.0.0/unordered_map:47,
                 from <source>:3:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-cxx-modules-trunk-20220427/include/c++/11.0.0/bits/unordered_map.h:141:7: note: 'std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map() [with _Key = const Entity; _Tp = std::bitset<24>; _Hash = std::hash<const Entity>; _Pred = std::equal_to<const Entity>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Entity, std::bitset<24> > >]'
 is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  141 |       unordered_map() = default;
```

[run](https://godbolt.org/z/GTa1f9ncj)

Comment: what do you expect `Entiry::operator()` to be used for?

Comment: code in your link looks ok, code compiles. Whats the issue?

Comment: the map never uses `value_type::operator()`. Its unclear why you think so

Comment: There is no point in having const keys since the existing keys are kept immutable inside the map.

Comment: @463035818 : question updated. operator calls `std::hash()` to provide a unique hash of an `Entity`.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 The map does not use an `operator()` overload for the key type for computing the hash.

Comment: @molbdnilo : so the hashing function cannot be part of `Entity` by overloading the operator, it has to be its own `struct` ?

Comment: Pretty much, but it can be any callable thing or type. (Well, you could say `unordered_map<Entity, bitset<24>, Entity>`, but that would cause a default `Entity` to be created just for computing the hash of other instances of `Entity`. It would not call `e(e)`when you want to add `e`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify a hash function for your map it defaults to `std::hash<Key>` with your key type.
So you will need to define this specialization of `std::hash`

```
template<>
struct std::hash<const Entity>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const Entity const& k) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<string>{}(k.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My confusion came from using the operator overloading technique with `unordered_set`, which **does** work !! See added `Record` in https://godbolt.org/z/zaPecMz13. Don't get the difference between `map` & `set` in this regard..  both need key hashing !

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 The `operator()` needs to be in a separate struct, which you can then specify as the hasher. Not in the class you're storing there. As for `unordered_set`, you specified `bitset<24>` as the hasher (which is invalid, but only seems to break when you try to insert something there).

Comment: @ExperNoob1 you could use `unordered_map<const Entity, bitset<24>,Entity>` to use `Entity` as key type and as hash at the same time, though thats unusual and confusing. I am not aware of any container that uses its element types `operator()`.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 Try adding something to your `unordered_set` and see it fail. Then make it `unordered_set<Record>` and see it keep failing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat first version of link OP provided used Record itself as hasher, which would work, but should not be done. For current link, it does not break, because unless you try to use functions, which call hasher, it does not actually try to call it (and break). `std::map` needs to synthesize `hasher(pair<key, value>)` out of `hasher(key)`, so it always using it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : I'm so doubly confused !! Indeed I used `Record` as its own hasher !! Never had a problem with that program, but still.. I agree with @463035818 : that's ridiculous ! Oh my.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 *"Never had a problem with that program"* What program? Using a type as its own hasher is normally wasteful, as each set/map will store an extra instance of it just to calculate the hashes. Not to mention that the users of the hash might be confused by `()` computing the hash.

Comment: I made a little gadget (multithread deletion of a huge list of files/folders from an input file) that uses an `unordered_set` of `Record`s to remove duplicates from the list of folders that become empty as a result (ought to de removed too), and it hashed `Record` against itself. Compiled, worked for years with no issues. But yes : wasteful & confusing (like you might think it would work with `map`s and try to perpetuate the nonsense !).